# jQuery - Downloading Textarea Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I download the textarea value/contents when I click a button? It should act like PHP:

```
<?php
$file = 'proxies.txt';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I just can't find any way on here to do it. I don't want it to make a href to click a second time to download. I just want to click a button and it will download a txt file containing the textarea's contents.

My current code that wont work:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    contentType =  'data:application/octet-stream,';
    uriContent = contentType + encodeURIComponent($('#proxiescontainer').val());
    $(this).setAttribute('href', uriContent);
});
```

Explanation:

- `#test` is the `a` tag wrapping the button;
- `#proxiescontainer` is the `textarea` itself;

So how can I get it to be a onClick download of the textarea's contents?

My AJAX:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "grab.php", true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

        var t = $('#proxiescontainer').scrollTop(), $d2 = $('#proxiescontainer').replaceWith('<button type="button" id="download" class="form-control button">Download</button><textarea id="proxiescontainer" class="form-control message-input" style="height: 250px!important;">' + xhttp.responseText + '</textarea>');

        if (t){ $('#proxiescontainer').scrollTop(t + $d2.outerHeight()); }

    }

}
```

Comment: `#proxiescontainer` not appear at `js` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Apprently Console says setAttribute isnt a function but it is? @guest271314

Comment: `setAttribute` is property of `DOM` element , not jQuery method ; to use `setAttribute` try using `DOM` element , e.g., `this.setAttribute()` , without jQuery wrapper , or use jQuery method `.attr()` `$(this).attr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using existing `js` `setAttribute()` is not a jQuery method ; to use on `DOM` element remove `jQuery()` wrapper

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    contentType =  'data:application/octet-stream,';
    uriContent = contentType + encodeURIComponent($('#proxiescontainer').val());
    this.setAttribute('href', uriContent);
});
```

alternatively using `Blob` `createObjectURL()` , `download` attribute

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  // create `a` element
  $("<a />", {
      // if supported , set name of file
      download: $.now() + ".txt",
      // set `href` to `objectURL` of `Blob` of `textarea` value
      href: URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([$("textarea").val()], {
          type: "text/plain"
        }))
    })
    // append `a` element to `body`
    // call `click` on `DOM` element `a`
    .appendTo("body")[0].click();
    // remove appended `a` element after "Save File" dialog,
    // `window` regains `focus` 
    $(window).one("focus", function() {
      $("a").last().remove()
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>download</button>
```

Comment: Works perfect I appreciate this! May I ask if you could comment whats happening? Just to help me understand :)

Comment: Actually one issue, I have AJAX to get the proxies and load them into the textare using .replaceWith to add the new textarea. When I make it so the button is also in the replaceWith so it only shows if there are proxies. The Javascript wont work. The blob one.

Comment: _"AJAX"_ not appear at original Question ? If alternative version using `Blob` does not return expected results , use initial version, with `jQuery()` wrapper removed from `this` ?

Comment: The initial way isnt working at all, And the blob version works just if I get the button to go into the HTML using AJAX xhttp it wont work for some reason.

Comment: Solution at post for original Question: _"jQuery - Downloading Textarea Contents - So how can I get it to be a onClick download of the textarea's contents?"_ Not following `ajax` portions , here . Why not included at original Question ?

Comment: I didn't think it was actually related; You see I have edited my question, You can see what the ajax is doing but for some reason the $("#download").click jquery wont find the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `ajax` not related to downloading contents of `textarea` as initially described at Question . See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Is ` $("#download").click()` inside `onreadystatechange` handler ? , following call to `.replaceWith()` ?

Comment: No, This is my current script: http://pastebin.com/kJLSvC34. Should I add the blob version inside the ready state?

Comment: Ok, I added it into the State Change and now it works fine :) I appreciate this help a ton dude!

Comment: _"Should I add the blob version inside the ready state?"_ Yes, `#download` element appear to be added to `DOM` asynchronously , current `js` at pastebin appear to call `#download` synchronously, where may , may not be added to `DOM` yet within `onreadystatechange` handler