# Downloading Textarea Contents with line breaks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to download the content of a textarea on button click to a .txt file in jQuery. I was able to use the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198936/jquery-downloading-textarea-contents)

and i was able to use this code;

```
$("#downloadtext").click(function() {
// create `a` element
$("<a />", {
    // if supported , set name of file
    download: $.now() + ".txt",
    // set `href` to `objectURL` of `Blob` of `textarea` value
    href: URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([$("#textarea-content").val()], {
        type: "text/plain"
      }))
  })
  // append `a` element to `body`
  // call `click` on `DOM` element `a`
  .appendTo("body")[0].click();
  // remove appended `a` element after "Save File" dialog,
  // `window` regains `focus` 
  $(window).one("focus", function() {
    $("a").last().remove()
  })
  });
```

I'm not sure why the downloaded file has no line break even when the content in the textarea has a line break. it looks like this[see image below];

[image]

But i would want it to look like this;

[image]

Not sure what is missing in the code above or why it is stripping out the line breaks.

Your helping point me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Call `.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n")` on the `.val()` of the textarea (the problem is that the text only has LF linebreaks, but for Windows you need CR & LF)

Comment: Works like charm... thank you so much @Chris G

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
    new Blob([$("textarea").val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '\r\n')], {
      type: "text/plain"
    }))
```